# How to make Tornado do not stop when ssh connection goes down?

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, tornado

I have Tornado example Hello World (http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)started on linode, I logged from my comp(command line) over ssh on linode and start like

```
python start.py
```

but problem is that when my local computer goes to sleep, my ssh connection from command line goes down and tornado example stops. How to make that example runs forever?

start.py is

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Its better to create an init or upstart script(this will convert it to a service/daemon) and add it to system startup. This will run the script automatically even if you reboot it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run it as `nohup python start.py &`

This will run the program in background, and won't be killed when the SSH connection drops. You can test it by disconnecting from the server as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) utility in linux and run commands there. When your ssh connection goes down screen will be detached. To connect to the screen later use -r(-R) param.

Comment: I personally like the screen solution way more.

For beginners, you can try it like this
screen bash
here comes your python execution
push Ctrl + a then Ctrl + d
to get back to this bash session, use screen -r